# Google Wallet: Adding test credit card results in error 130319

Tags: android-pay

I had set up Google wallet for digital goods on my website (in development) quite a while ago. Maybe in the summer or so.

Everything worked fine, now I have a new design, and I'm trying to actually implement it, but I keep getting an error when I am trying to add a test credit card from here: https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/testing

The error is:

> Uh oh. There was a problem. We couldn't start your purchase because of
>   a technical issue. 130319 16:55:47-0400 FCWI6O

You see the error codes at the bottom? **130319**  is always the same...

I get the same error when I am trying to buy a virtual piece of cake here: https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial#7

This leads me to belive, that I didn't mess up my code, but there is an issue somewhere else.

What's going on? Is there a problem with the test credit cards? Is sandbox down?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Received an answer on the Google forum:

> Can you please try adding the test card(s) directly to your sandbox
>   customer Wallet account: https://wallet-web.sandbox.google.com/manage

And that did the trick! I can now buy my virtual piece of cake again... :-)